# SIGINT signal will stop client application during scanf/fgets

Tags: c, scanf, client-server, fgets, sigint

I have a Client-Server application written in C language. This is not a professional poject, so everything I do is from command line (ubuntu terminal). Whenever the client code requires an input from the user, I use an fgets to take said input.
The problem is that if the user wants to stop the input process and exit the server by sending a CTRL+C signal (SIGINT), this won't work.

Specifically, what happens is this:

1. Client code asks for input and uses fgets to get one;
2. User presses CTRL+C *while* the client code is waiting for input;
3. Client code won't stop (if it stops, then the client code will send a specific kill signal to the server and shut the connection down);
4. Client will print on screen ^C;
5. If you try to press anything else, client code will just display it on the screen while you do the input, but if you press ENTER you won't send anything to the Server.

Therefore, the connection is stuck and the client is forever stopped in this input operation.

I don't know how to fix this. What i want is my client code to ask for input, if the user presses CTRL+C then the client code MUST stop and send such kill signal to the server. How can I do that?

I also tried with scanf like this:

```
   while ((scanf("%s", buff)) == -1) EINTR_ABORT("Errore di scanf");
     getchar();
```

(I know I should never use scanf, but for some reason my professor is fine with it -and I know is kinda sad but whatever-)

This is my fgets:

```
if(fgets(buff_ID, sizeof(buff_ID), stdin)== NULL)
   EINTR_ABORT("Errore di fgets");
```

Where this is EINTR_ABORT:

```
#define ISTANT_ABORT(warning) ({ \
    fprintf(stderr, "%s: %s.\n", warning, strerror(errno)); \
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);\
})

#define EINTR_ABORT(warning) ({ \
    if(errno != EINTR) \
        ISTANT_ABORT(warning); \
})
```

My professor never pointed this issue out, but he (obviously, because why not after all) expects us to solve it on our own in this project. I tried my best and never worked out anything that would actually fix the issue.

Comment: `scanf` is fine for toy projects. But its not for real life code.

Comment: I don't think I understand your question.  The `SIGINT` signal isn't supposed to send a kill signal to the server. Did you perhaps mean: *"The application should abort and the server should be notified of it?"* And if so, would you kindly post the code?

Comment: We really need to see more of your code. If you do nothing, the default action for `SIGINT` is to terminate the program. So, you probably want to use `sigaction` to install a signal handler. Then, when the signal occurs, the `fgets` will return `NULL` and `errno` will be `EINTR`. You can detect this and have the client do whatever is appropriate to terminate the server. But, _what_ you need to have the client do depends on the protocol [that you devise] with the server. That is, do you send a special message with a "terminate" flag?

Comment: Thank you Craig Estey, I think I understood part of the solution, I'll try to work it out, and if it does not work, I'll send more code (but I need time to select it properly, as it's... massive, let's say ahahah). Thank you all very much btw

Comment: Haris yes, that's what the app should do. When Client is hit by CTRL+C, the client should stop. When hit with CTRL+C, a signal handler should notice the server. It already works when not in input session, the problem is during inputs.

Answer (score 1):

You can handle INT signal and set a flag signalling that user interrupted input.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>

static sig_atomic_t interrupted = 0;
static void sigint_handler(int)
{
    interrupted = 1;
}

int main(void)
{
    struct sigaction act;

    act.sa_handler = sigint_handler; // Set new SIGINT handler
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);       // No need to mask signals in handler
    act.sa_flags = 0;                // Don't set SA_RESTART flag

    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &act, NULL) != 0)
        perror("sigaction");

    char str[256];
    char *ret = fgets(str, sizeof(str), stdin);

    if (interrupted)
    {
        // Handle interrupt here
        printf("Interrupted!\n");

    } else if (ret)
    {
        // Handle fgets result here
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Note: don't use `signal()` function for setting up signal handler because on Linux it applies `SA_RESTART` flag.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I should do this everytime instead of fgets(...), right?

Comment: It depends on desired logic of your application. This is simplest example. You can create wrapper function for `fgets()` and return specific result for interruption. If signal handling should not affect other parts you can save old signal action before `fgets()` and restore it after `fgets()` returned. If your application must continue to work after interrupted input you need to block `SIGINT` and reset `interrupted` flag while signal is blocked, otherwise race condition is possible.

Comment: In more sophisticated case you can create file descriptor for signals with `signalfd()` and use multiplexed I/O. But in this case you need to implement your own analog of `fgets()` for both catching signals and data on stdin.

Comment: so dimich what you suggest is that I write my own non blocking version of fgets? So I think this also goes for read and write, right? Because in my code for socket I use read/write, but they are blocking, therefore they may be part of the problem, right?

Comment: @ZODIACK It's hard to advise something without knowing entire scope of your task. If you just want to perform some actions before termination on SIGINT you can use standard `fgets()`, just check flag after `fgets()` or other blocking function returned. But in general, yes, if you want to read from several descriptors including stdin and signal descriptor then multiplexed IO with `poll()` or `epoll` would be a good choise.